# Reducing the number of parameters of a quantum state from 4 to 3

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-states

We have a quantum state

$$
|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle,
$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers, i.e. $\alpha = a + bi$ and $\beta = c + di$. Therefore, our current parameter count is 4.

From [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205881/how-many-parameters-are-needed-to-specify-a-quantum-state) question, I understand how you can ignore one parameter because of global phase to go from 3 to 2 parameters. However, I don't understand how to go from 4 to 3 parameters with $\alpha^*\alpha + \beta^*\beta = 1$. Expanding this equation we get

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha^*\alpha + \beta^*\beta &= (a-bi)(a+bi) + (c-di)(c+di) \\
&= a^2 + abi - abi -b^2i^2 + c^2 + cdi - cdi -d^2i^2 \\
&= a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 1
\end{align}
$$

However, I don't understand how this expression helps us get rid of one parameter. I've been working with quantum computing for almost two years now, so I guess I'm missing to notice something elementary.

Comment: Perhaps there is something really obvious here, but you're left with a constraint upon 4 real parameters, which means that 3 of them are independent.

Comment: @DanielC ohhh, I see it now. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a more conventional way to see this:

Write in polar form $\alpha=\vert\alpha\vert e^{i\phi_a}$, $\beta=\vert\beta\vert e^{i \phi_b}$. Then your state is
$$
e^{i\phi_a}\left( \vert\alpha\vert \vert 0\rangle + e^{-i(\phi_b-\phi_a)}\vert \beta\vert\vert 1\rangle\right)\, .
$$
You can eliminate the *overall* phase $e^{i\phi_a}$ as two states differing by an overall phase are equivalent.  Your are then left with $3$ parameters:  the magnitudes $\vert \alpha\vert$, $\vert \beta\vert$ and the phase *difference* $e^{i(\phi_b-\phi_a)}$.

To bring this down from $3$ to $2$, eliminate the overall phase $e^{i\phi_a}$ and write $\vert \alpha\vert=\cos\theta$, $\vert \beta\vert =\sin\theta$ so that $\vert\alpha\vert^2+\vert \beta\vert^2=1$, and $\varphi=\phi_b-\phi_a$.  You then have
\begin{align}
\vert\psi\rangle\sim \cos\theta \vert 0\rangle + e^{i \varphi}\sin\theta \vert 1\rangle\, .
\end{align}

Comment: And then how do you insert the unitary constraint to get down to two parameters?

Comment: $\vert\alpha\vert^2+\vert\beta\vert^2=1$ so write $\vert\alpha\vert=\cos(\theta)$, $\vert\beta\vert=\sin(\theta)$ and $\varphi=\phi_b-\phi_a$.  You now only have $\theta$ and $\varphi$ as parameters.

Comment: @epelaaez To normalise the state, divide $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by $\sqrt{|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2}$. Note that “unitary” is a property of operators, not of states.

Comment: Thank you @ZeroTheHero, that clears up my doubts!

Comment: Yes @gandalf61, I was just using the term “unitary” to refer to the fact that $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$. Probably should’ve referred to it differently. But thanks!